# My Code should remove all false values but it is not?

Tags: javascript

My Code should remove the false values but it is only removing first false value in a given array

```js
const arr = [7, "ate", "", false, 9]



function bouncer(arr) {
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (!arr[i]) {
      arr.splice(i, 1)
    }
  }
  return arr;
}

console.log(bouncer(arr))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't iterate upwards AND shorten your array like this; `splice` has the side effect of modifying the original array.

Consider what happens in the case `[false, false, true]`

1. `i = 0`, `length = 3`, `arr = [(false), false, true]` -> arr becomes `[false, true]`
2. `i = 1`, `length = 2`, `arr = [false, (true)]`-> arr stays `[false, true]`

(parenthesis denotes current target)

Solutions:

- Iterate down, not up

  ```js
  for (let i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0; --i) if (!arr[i]) arr.splice(i, 1);
  ```
- Use `Array.prototype.filter` instead (this will also improve readability)

  ```js
  arr = arr.filter((item) => !!item);
  ```

Answer (score 3):

Why don't use `filter` like:

```js
const arr = [false,7, "ate", "", false, 9];
console.log(arr.filter(el => el !== false));
```

Reference:

- [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Comment: Sidenote: you can use `arr.filter(el => !el))` for falsey values

Comment: @DadiBit You could do that, but that will *keep*  all falseys instead of removing them. If  a strict check for boolean `false` is needed, `el => el !== false` is the way to go. If any falsey should be removed the filter should be `el => !!el`

Comment: @derpirscher answer for me :)

Answer (score 0):

The `.filter()` approach as suggested by Rossaini or PaulS is definitely a better path to follow. However, your approach works if you work through the array backwards:

```js
const test=[7, "ate", "", false, 9];

function bouncer(arr) {
  if (!arr.length) return [];
  for (let i=arr.length-1; i--;){
    if(!arr[i]){
        arr.splice(i, 1)
      }
  }
  return arr;
}

console.log(bouncer(test));
console.log(bouncer([]));
// solution with filter:
console.log(test.filter(e=>e));
```

You need to consider that `.splice()` actually changes the source array you are working on. Using an increasing index `i` you will skip an entry each time an element is deleted from the array. By walking through the array backwards (from the end to the beginning) as done with `for (let i=arr.length; i--;)` you will avoid this problem.

Comment: On the first iteration with `let i=arr.length;`, `arr[i]` will be "out of bounds", you can start from `length - 1`

Comment: (with my suggested change you'd also need to handle the `0` length condition slightly differently as the first iteration's `i` would also then become `-1` which is truthy)

Comment: @PaulS, of course! ‍♂️ silly oversight on my part. Thanks for putting it right! .

Comment: fixed the zero-length case too - but in any case: the filter method is to be preferred!!!

Answer (score 0):

There's a function for that

```
const noFalse = arr.filter(el => !!el)
```

Comment: Did you mean to `!!`?

Comment: I did, thanks. Typing on mobile. ‍♂️

Answer (score 0):

You can try Array.prototype.filter

```
bouncer = arr =>  arr.filter(elm =>  !!elm)
var array = [ false, null, 0, "", undefined,NaN , true]
var newArr = bouncer(array )
console.log(newArr )
```

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is, when you do `splice`, you are adjusting your indexes. You could have added a simple debug statement like `console.log` to identify whats happening with your code.

I just added a sample stdout line before doing validation

```js
function bouncer(arr) {
  for(let i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
    console.log(arr[i]);
    if(!arr[i]){
        arr.splice(i, 1)
      }
  }
  return arr;
}
console.log(bouncer([7, "ate", "", false, 9]));
```

And your code does print as below

```js
[/private/tmp]$ node sto.js
7
ate

9
[ 7, 'ate', false, 9 ]
```

So if you observe, after `""` string, as you have used `splice` the index got adjusted and `false` missed from iteration.

#### Solutions

1. Use another array and push all non invalid items into it.
2. Use filter which does same for you automatically.